# Vue3 custom div creating

Tags: vuejs3

hello i am a vue 3 beginner. I'm trying to create a custom div, but I couldn't understand how to do it.

```
<template>
    <MyDiv>
        <Hello></Hello>
    </MyDiv>
</template>

<script>
import Hello from './tools/Hello';

export default {
    name: "LayoutEmpty",
    components: {
        'Hello': Hello
    },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define each components first, specifically the MyDiv and Hello components. [This](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-basics.html#base-example) should help.

Furthermore, it looks like you want to use a custom component inside another custom component, you would need to leverage [Slot](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-slots.html).

I mocked up a quick solution template to what you might be looking for. I hope this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-tamas-fef52) will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You completely misunderstood the subject, I can already do these things :) I want to create a special div and I want to print the components I want inside

Comment: Oh my bad, I thought this special div is the "MyDiv" you're trying to implement. Could you clarify what you're trying to achieve more then?

Comment: Actually what I want to do is
I want it to appear as `<myDiv></div>` in dev tools

Comment: Ah I see. In that case, that's not achievable because component names can't be the same as [reserved HTML elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element).